# how to get javascript function on click on button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`onclick` on assign to rm button , I want to get on rm names listed as a dropdown

my view,
gu_rent_property_list.html.erb

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
    <%= button_tag "Assign To Rm" type: 'button', onclick: "update_subscategories_div(<%=property.category_id%>)", class: 'btn btn-default'%>
<% end %>`
```

Iam getting syntax error for this.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: You can't use a ruby tag within a ruby tag.

Comment: i need a button there, on click on that button i should get category id. then how i will do it

Comment: javascript and controller part is ok. only that link is the problem. on click , ineed to fire javascript here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using erb the wrong way. The solution is simple:

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
    <%= button_tag "Assign To Rm", type: 'button', onclick: "update_subscategories_div(#{property.category_id})", class: 'btn btn-default'%>
<% end %>
```